# What's the simplest way to get a Spark DataFrame from arbitrary Array Data in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, nlp, nd4j

I've been breaking my head about this one for a couple of days now. It feels like it should be intuitively easy... Really hope someone can help!

I've built an `org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray` of word occurrence from some semi-structured data like this:

```
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
import org.nd4s.Implicits._

val docMap = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Map[Int,Int]] //of the form Map(phrase -> Map(phrasePosition -> word)
val words = ArrayBuffer("word_1","word_2","word_3",..."word_n")
val windows = ArrayBuffer("$phrase,$phrasePosition_1","$phrase,$phrasePosition_2",..."$phrase,$phrasePosition_n") 

var matrix = Nd4j.create(windows.length*words.length).reshape(windows.length,words.length)
for (row <- matrix.shape(0)){
    for(column <- matrix.shape(1){
        //+1 to (row,column) if word occurs at phrase, phrasePosition indicated by window_n.
    }
}
val finalmatrix = matrix.T.dot(matrix) // to get co-occurrence matrix
```

So far so good...

Downstream of this point I need to integrate the data into an existing pipeline in Spark, and use that implementation of pca etc, so I need to create a DataFrame, or at least an RDD. If I knew the number of words and/or windows in advance I could do something like:

```
case class Row(window : String, word_1 : Double, word_2 : Double, ...etc)

val dfSeq = ArrayBuffer[Row]()
for (row <- matrix.shape(0)){
    dfSeq += Row(windows(row),matrix.get(NDArrayIndex.point(row), NDArrayIndex.all()))
}
sc.parallelize(dfSeq).toDF("window","word_1","word_2",...etc)
```

but the number of windows and words is determined at runtime. I'm looking for a WindowsxWords `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` as output, input is a WindowsxWords `org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray`

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after several days work it looks like the simple answer is: there isn't one. In fact, it looks like trying to use `Nd4j` in this context *at all* is a bad idea for several reasons:

1. It's (really) hard to get data out of the native `INDArray` format once you've put it in.
2. Even using something like [guava](https://github.com/google/guava), the .data() method [brings everything on heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839617/nd4j-arrays-their-shapes-getting-data-into-a-list) which will quickly become expensive.
3. You've got the added hassle of having to compile an assembly jar or use hdfs etc to handle the library itself.

I did also consider using [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) which may actually provide a viable solution but carries some of the same problems and [can't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898093/can-spark-and-the-scalanlp-library-breeze-be-used-together) on distributed data structures.

Unfortunately, using native Spark / Scala datatypes, although easier once you know how, is - for someone like me coming from Python + numpy + pandas heaven at least - painfully convoluted and ugly.

Nevertheless, I did implement this solution successfully:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Vector,Matrix,DenseMatrix,DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

//first make a pseudo-matrix from Scala Array[Double]:
var rowSeq = Seq.fill(windows.length)(Array.fill(words.length)(0d))

//iterate through 'rows' and 'columns' to fill it:
for (row 0 until windows.length){
    for (column 0 until words.length){
        // rowSeq(row)(column) += 1 if word occurs at phrase, phrasePosition indicated by window_n.
    }
}

//create Spark DenseMatrix
val rows : Array[Double] = rowSeq.transpose.flatten.toArray
val matrix = new DenseMatrix(windows.length,words.length,rows)
```

One of the main operations that I needed Nd4J for was `matrix.T.dot(matrix)` but it turns out that you can't multiply 2 matrices of Type `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix` together, one of them (A) has to be a `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix` and - you guessed it - you can't call `matrix.transpose()` on a `RowMatrix`, only on a `DenseMatrix`! Since it's not really relevant to the question, I'll leave that part out, except to explain that what comes out of that step is a `RowMatrix`. Credit is also due [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977151/how-to-convert-a-mllib-matrix-to-a-spark-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969521/how-to-compute-the-inverse-of-a-rowmatrix-in-apache-spark) for the final part of the solution:

```
val rowMatrix : [RowMatrix] = transposeAndDotDenseMatrix(matrix)

// get DataFrame from RowMatrix via DenseMatrix
val newdense = new DenseMatrix(rowMatrix.numRows().toInt,rowMatrix.numCols().toInt,rowMatrix.rows.collect.flatMap(x => x.toArray)) // the call to collect() here is undesirable...
val matrixRows = newdense.rowIter.toSeq.map(_.toArray)
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(matrixRows).toDF("Rows")

// then separate columns:
val df2 = (0 until words.length).foldLeft(df)((df, num) => 
df.withColumn(words(num), $"Rows".getItem(num)))
.drop("Rows")
```

Would love to hear improvements and suggestions on this, thanks.